# What is this illustration style called?

Tags: style-identification

I'm trying to find a better version of this image for glass etching and I have no idea what it is called to search for it online. What do I search for in Google Images to find a better version this image?

[image]

Comment: This might be a long shot, but have you tried doing an inverted search in google? Results surprise me sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

**arabesque** would be another good descriptor for that kind of imagery

Answer (score 1):

You can search to find many examples of ***SCROLLWORK*** (and scroll shapes) that when "mirrored" (duplicated and arranged to touch) to build the symmetrical shapes you want. They can be used in combinations to be as intricate as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The following keywords resemble that style:

- Floral
- Decorative
- Ornament

Other keywords

- Swirl
- Line Art

Comment: Just to add to the list, decal and filigree are good ones too.